# XML: 'src' is not an unexpected token. The expected token is '='

Tags: ssis

I have a DTSX code developed in VS 2008 running on SQL 2008. Now I need to migrate to 2017 using VS 2015.
The task of this DTSX is to get XML from a 3rd party web site using the web service they provided.
Now I always get this error:

> 'src' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 8, position 7.

I tried the Encrypted package.

```
public void Main()

{

    String requestUrl = `"https://myTemlurl/XMLj/X-ShipmentStatus";`

    Uri conwayUri = new Uri(requestUrl);

    String username = "userABC";

    String password = "pwd1234";

    String authType = "basic";

    String tracking = "VEG123456";

    NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
    myCache.Add(conwayUri, authType, myCred);

    string today = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Today.Day.ToString() + "/" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString().Remove(0, 2);

    ArrayList trackNums = new ArrayList();
    `trackNums.Add(tracking);`

    String xmlRequest = "";
    xmlRequest += "<ShipmentStatusRequest testmode=\"N\">";
    xmlRequest += "<CustomerNumber>493116471</CustomerNumber>";
    xmlRequest += "<ReportType>M</ReportType>";
    xmlRequest += "<ShipmentRole>B</ShipmentRole>";
    xmlRequest += "</ShipmentStatusRequest>";

    // Encode the Request String and set up the POST data
    xmlRequest = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(xmlRequest);
    String postData = "ShipmentStatusRequest=" + xmlRequest;
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    byte [] postBuffer = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    // Set up the HTTP Request
    HttpWebRequest wReq = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(conwayUri);
    wReq.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    wReq.ContentLength = postBuffer.Length;
    wReq.Method="POST";
    wReq.Timeout=180000;
    wReq.KeepAlive = false;
    wReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 180000;
    wReq.Credentials = myCache;
    wReq.PreAuthenticate = true;

    Stream reqStream = null;
    reqStream = wReq.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(postBuffer,0,postBuffer.Length);
    reqStream.Close();  

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse wResp = (HttpWebResponse)wReq.GetResponse();
        Stream respStream = wResp.GetResponseStream();
        XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(respStream);
        XmlDocument xmlStatus = new XmlDocument();
        xmlStatus.Load(xmlReader);

        //The entire XML Response String
        String respString = xmlStatus.InnerXml;
        respString = respString.Replace("<PRONmbr>", "</Shipment><Shipment><PRONmbr>");
        respString = respString.Replace("</ShipmentStatusResponse>", "</Shipment></ShipmentStatusResponse>");
        respString = respString.Replace("?dest=privacy.\"></Shipment>", "?dest=privacy.\">");

        Dts.Variables["User::Results"].Value = respString;

        // Clean up resources
        //reqStream.Close();
        xmlReader.Close();
        respStream.Close();
        wResp.Close();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;                
    }
}
```

I would like to know where I went wrong.
Thanks

Comment: By the way: this line reqStream = wReq.GetRequestStream(); gives me
Length = '((System.Net.ConnectStream)reqStream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
Position = '((System.Net.ConnectStream)reqStream).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Comment: HI everyone, after I changed https:// to http://, job works, it worries me because it should be a secured url. Any ideas?  BTW: developer who wrote those code left long time ago and no clue who should contact on 3rd party side.